# What Exception to use to detect host/reciever has gone down/failed?

Tags: java, exception, tcp

I have created a TCP server-client application in java which exchange periodic messages between them.
As part of failure management, i need to detect the failure of either host/client and then call my custom function.
Which exception in Java will catch just this part?
Will SocketException work here? I want to call failure management only when host/client go down and not on any other issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the server going down (being shutdown, resulting in an [IOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)), the server not being available when you initiate a connection ([ConnectException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/rmi/ConnectException.html)), and the server going offline (imagine a network cable being pulled out). This will usually manifest itself with a [SocketTimeoutException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) or similar.

I would run a process up and try out all the scenarios you expect to handle. You'll have to deal with timeouts differently to explicit disconnects etc.